# Why can the following code not solve letter combination question?

Tags: python

```
def letterCombinations(digits: str) -> List[str]:
    result = []
    check_dict = {'2': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
            '3': ['d', 'e', 'f'],
            '4': ['g', 'h', 'i'],
            '5': ['j', 'k', 'l'],
            '6': ['m', 'n', 'o'],
            '7': ['p', 'q', 'r', 's'],
            '8': ['t', 'u', 'v'],
            '9': ['w', 'x', 'y', 'z']}

    if len(digits) == 0:
        return []
    elif len(digits) == 1:
        return check_dict.get(digits)
    else:
        digits1 = list(digits)
        dec_dict = {}
                
        for i in digits1:
            value = check_dict.get(i)
            dec_dict[i] = value
    
        to_do_value = list(dec_dict.values())
        for i in to_do_value[0]:
            for j in to_do_value[1:]:
                for k in j:
                    z = i + k
                    result.append(z)

    return result
```

The question is Leetcode Q17: [17. Letter Combinations of a Phone Number](https://leetcode.com/problems/letter-combinations-of-a-phone-number/)
. Most of the test cases passed but the code outputs `[]` if the input is like `'22'` or `'99'`. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: What should the output be instead of `[]` if the input is `'22'`?

Comment: it should like this:
["aa","ab","ac","ba","bb","bc","ca","cb","cc"]

Comment: What do you observe when you use a debugger or place some print statements inside the `else` part to see what is going on in this case with the variables `dec_dict`, `digits1`, `to_do_value`, `i`, `j`, `k`? Is it what you observe different from what you intended?

Answer (score 0):

here in this for code snippet

```
    digits1 = list(digits)
    dec_dict = {}
            
    for i in digits1:
        value = check_dict.get(i)
        dec_dict[i] = value
```

when you are creating digits 1 it looks like this (e.g: '22')

```
['2', '2']
```

so *in the first iteration in the dec_dict a key of value '2' is added*, so when you try to add another '2' in the second iteration the dictionary just uses the new value of that iteration instead of creating a new one, **as two same keys cannot exist in a dictionary**

so in the end after this loop the dec_dict looks like this

```
{'2': ['a', 'b', 'c']}
```

now for this snippet

```
    to_do_value = list(dec_dict.values())
    for i in to_do_value[0]:
        for j in to_do_value[1:]:
            for k in j:
                z = i + k
                result.append(z)
```

todo_values becomes equal to [['a', 'b', 'c']]
and **todo_values[1:] does not exist**. Thus the loop doesn't run and nothing is appended to the result and result remains empty

Answer (score -2):

you can use a recursive function ('backtrack') for this.

```
from typing import List

class Solution:
    def letterCombinations(self, digits: str) -> List[str]:
        def backtrack(combination, next_digits):
            if not next_digits:
                result.append(combination)
                return
            for letter in check_dict[next_digits[0]]:
                backtrack(combination + letter, next_digits[1:])

        result = []
        check_dict = {
            '2': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
            '3': ['d', 'e', 'f'],
            '4': ['g', 'h', 'i'],
            '5': ['j', 'k', 'l'],
            '6': ['m', 'n', 'o'],
            '7': ['p', 'q', 'r', 's'],
            '8': ['t', 'u', 'v'],
            '9': ['w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
        }

        if digits:
            backtrack('', digits)
        
        return result
```

Comment: But why does the original code not work correctly?

Comment: Is this your original code or just a copy of one of the submissions already made to Leetcode?